# Incompatible command arguments for netstat?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, home-networking, netstat

The command `netstat -ano 192.168.1.1` works, whereas adding the -p flag, i.e.`netstat -anop 192.168.1.1`just displays the command-line parameters with descriptions like if you'd just typed `netstat` without any arguments. Why is this the case? The0 arguments just incompatible with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows `netstat` understands `-p` as:

> `-p protocol`
>   Shows connections for the protocol specified by `protocol`.

While e.g. in Linux `-p` takes no option-argument:

> `-p`
>   Show which processes are using which sockets

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat#Parameters))

By the tag you used I understand you're on Windows 10. You specified `-p` without `protocol`. The tool did not know what to do and displayed the overview of options to help you fix the command. I guess `-p protocol` was there.

Comment: That makes sense. Weird that the command would be defined differently between OS's like that though.